# C++ recursive templates with specialisation for tree algorithm

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, recursive-templates

I'm developing a tree-like algorithm using recursive c++ templates. I manage to reproduce my issues with the simplified algorithm below. The algorithm takes a single integer as an input. It computes two integers that are functions of the previous integer, and then it goes recursively: for each of the integers computed, it computes another two with the exact same function (which is also a function of the depth), until a stopping criterion is met.

I've written the following code using templates. I'm using this design choice because I ultimately want to implement the algorithm in HLS.

```
#define max_depth 5
#define two_to_maxdepth 32


// recursive template
template<unsigned int depth, unsigned int two_to_depth>
void split( int in[two_to_depth], int out[two_to_maxdepth], int aux[depth+1] )
{

  int next[two_to_depth*2];
  for (unsigned int ipart=0; ipart < two_to_depth; ++ipart){
    next[ipart]=ipart*in[ipart];
    next[ipart+two_to_depth]=ipart*in[ipart]+depth;
  }
  split<depth+1, two_to_depth*2>( next, out, aux);
}


// specialize
template<>
void split( int in[two_to_maxdepth], int out[two_to_maxdepth], int aux[max_depth+1])
{
  in=out;
}


int main()
{
  int in[1];
  int out[two_to_maxdepth];
  int aux[1];
  split<0,1>(in, out,aux);
}
```

However, it's not compiling, because it doesn't manage to infer the value of `depth`. I'm confused by this: the value of `depth` is specified in the template instantiation. Sorry if the question is too trivial, but I fail to see the reason.

Comment: "the value of depth is specified in the template instantiation" But not in the template specialization, `template<> void split(...)`. The compiler can't figure out what parameters you are specializing for. Make it `template<> void split<max_depth, two_to_maxdepth>(...)`

Comment: Unrelated, `in=out;` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It merely assigns one pointer to another, it doesn't actually copy the data between two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template<unsigned int depth_plus_one, unsigned int two_to_depth>
void split( int(& in)[two_to_depth], int (&out)[two_to_maxdepth], int (&aux)[depth_plus_one] )
{
  constexpr int depth=depth_plus_one-1;
```

This gets rid of forcing the compiler to invert x+1 to deduce x, and blocks function argument decay of arrays to pointers.

Also fix the termination case.  Both references on the arrays, and `in=out` not doing what you think it does.

Using `std::array` instead of raw C style arrays may help.  But even there, your out parameters should be references, and in.should be const references.

Now this still doesn't work, because `aux` is the wrong size in yohr recursive call.  Why does `aux` even exist?

```
constexpr unsigned lg(unsigned x){
  if(x<=1) return 0;
  return 1+lg(x/2);
}

template<unsigned sz>
void split(int const(&In)[sz], int(&Out)[sz]){
  for(int i=0;i<sz;++i)
    Out[i]=In[i];
}

template<unsigned in, unsigned out>
void split( int const(&In)[in], int(&Out)[out] )
{
  int Next[in*2];

  for (unsigned i=0; i<In; ++i){
    Next[i]=i*In[i];
    Next[i+in]=i*In[i]+lg(in); // maybe +1?
  }
  split(Next, Out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this more or less did the trick. Together with the first of your suggestions, I specified the template parameters in the template specialisation. That worked perfectly well